# How to write a for loop for .js script in mongo to pass database name variable in the text file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have list of database names in .txt file like below

local
test
admin

How can i pass arguments dynamically instead of hardcoded in .js scripts for mono go.

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('test');  

date = new Date()  


date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1)  

yesterday = Math.floor(date.getTime()/1000).toString(16)       

db.coll.find({_id : {$gt : new ObjectId(yesterday + "0000000000000000")}} , {_id:1})
```

Comment: which bit specifically do you want to set dynamically?

Comment: I want to pass database name 'test' exists in the first statement db = db.getSiblingDB('test');

Answer (score 1):

You can pass variables to the MongoDB shell like this:

```
mongo --eval 'dbname="test"' foo.js
```

Which you then can use in your script:

```
derick@whisky:/tmp $ cat foo.js 

db = db.getSiblingDB(database);  

date = new Date()  
date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1)  

yesterday = Math.floor(date.getTime()/1000).toString(16)       

print( db.so.findOne({_id : {$gt : new ObjectId(yesterday + "0000000000000000")}} , {_id:1})._id )
```